# Как переопределить метод класса Dart?

Tags: конструктор, dart

Как переопределить метод класса ***Dart***? Создал класс, задача которого просто переопределить `onAdd(int event){}`:

```
class _PageBehaviorSubject extends BehaviorSubject<int> {

  factory _PageBehaviorSubject({
      int seedValue,
      void onListen(),
      Future<dynamic> onCancel(),
      {bool sync: false}}
      )=> BehaviorSubject<int>(seedValue: seedValue, onListen: onListen, onCancel: onCancel, sync: sync);

  @override
  void onAdd(int event) {
    //..
  }
}
```

Когда я переопределил метод, IDE сказала:

> The generative constructor 'BehaviorSubject({T seedValue, () → void
>   onListen, () → Future onCancel, bool sync: false}) →
>   BehaviorSubject' expected, but factory found.

Я скопировал параметры конструктора родителя, а затем просто вызвал конструктор родителя внутри своего конструктора. Ошибка пропала, но объект своего класса создать не могу, ошибка:

> type 'BehaviorSubject' is not a subtype of type
>   '_PageBehaviorSubject'

BehaviorSubject, как я понимаю, и не должен быть подтипом моего класса, поэтому не могу понять, почему такое выводить. Как создать класс, который переопределяет 1 метод класса?

Comment: что за класс BehaviorSubject?

Comment: @Grundy https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html

Comment: ты неверно используешь `factory`. она тебе точно нужна? [Use the factory keyword when implementing a constructor that doesn’t always create a new instance of its class. For example, a factory constructor might return an instance from a cache, or it _might return an instance of a **subtype**_.](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors) Вот ты и возвращаешь сейчас из нее `BehaviorSubject` который не подтип, поэтому и ошибка.

Comment: @Grundy просто когда убираю factory, даже скомпилить не дает, пишет `The generative constructor...` в вопросе есть текст ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `BehaviorSubject<T>` отсутствует обычный конструктор, и есть только `factory`.

Поэтому нельзя использовать `extends`.

Вместо этого нужно использовать `implements`:

```
class _PageBehaviorSubject implements BehaviorSubject<int> {

  final BehaviorSubject<int> _subj;
  _PageBehaviorSubject({
      int seedValue,
      void onListen(),
      Future<dynamic> onCancel(),
      {bool sync: false}}
      ): _subj = BehaviorSubject<int>(seedValue: seedValue, onListen: onListen, onCancel: onCancel, sync: sync);

  void onAdd(int event) {
    _subj.onAdd(event);
  }
  /* далее должна быть имплементация всех остальных методов*/
}
```

---

Проблема в неверном вызове базового конструктора.

Для его вызова нужно использовать ключевое [слово `super`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#invoking-a-non-default-superclass-constructor), например так:

```
_PageBehaviorSubject({
  int seedValue,
  void onListen(),
  Future<dynamic> onCancel(),
  {bool sync: false}}
  ): super(seedValue: seedValue, onListen: onListen, onCancel: onCancel, sync: sync){}
```

Comment: пишет `The generative constructor 'BehaviorSubject({T seedValue, () → void onListen, () → Future onCancel, bool sync: false}) → BehaviorSubject' expected, but factory found.` Generative в этом случае, как я понимаю - обычный конструктор. А super вызывает не обычный, а factory конструктор.

Comment: @Maxgmer, а ты убрал у себя `factory`?

Comment: да, скопировал.

Comment: @Maxgmer, там немного другой прием нужно, скоро дополню ответ

Comment: блин, громоздко как-то получилось, implement - это как создание полностью нового класса по скелету методов родителя? Просто там очень много методов.. Но ладно, всё равно спасибо.

Comment: @Maxgmer, `implements` - это как реализация интерфейса, то есть, всех публичных методов. Ну и это только в том случае когда нет обычных конструкторов

Comment: попробую может как-нибудь присвоить методу родителя свою функцию после создания, вроде как методы - объекты типа function в dart.